# could not connect to push server error in android application using parse.com

Tags: android, push-notification

I've gone through the push guide (on parse.com) several times with 'new project' and also 'existing project' option but in all my tests, I haven't been able to get the notifications - on my phone or the simulator. The dashboard shows that the push notifications have been sent. LogCat shows the following errors. How do I solve this?

```
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060): could not connect to push server
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1002)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at com.parse.PushService$2.doInBackground(PushService.java:468)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at com.parse.PushService$2.doInBackground(PushService.java:428)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at com.parse.os.ParseAsyncTask$2.call(ParseAsyncTask.java:215)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
11-22 05:43:17.619: E/com.parse.PushService(5060):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I'm doing the Push Android guide and following the exact instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you **pushwoosh**. Its tried an tested. Follow: [Link1](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/enabling-gcm-services-for-google-api/) and then [Link2](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-push-notification-sdk-configuration-guide/)

Answer (score 1):

On parse.com go to your application and then click on settings. There should be a Push Notifications section. Enable 'Client push enabled?'.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't enabled it before. Though now that I've enabled it, I'm still not getting any notification on my client - using either my phone or the simulator. LogCat doesn't show any errors.

Comment: I just read that push notifications don't work on the simulator. Though I also tested on my phone and got no notification.

Comment: The problem arose for me again the same day I commented. For the parse website I got it working when I selected 'Segment' instead of 'Everyone' for the 'Send To' option and then three dropdown boxes appeared. When I clicked the last one a 'Broadcast' option appeared. I clicked this and tried to send the push and it came through on my device.